# Ubuntu download with wget and parameters

Tags: downloads, wget

I tied to download a .torrent file via wget but it don't work. 
I tried it with

```
wget "http://abc/?page=download&tid=348168" -o test.torrent
```

and also

```
wget "http://abc/index.php?page=download&tid=348168" -o test.torrent
```

but it downloads only a file named index.php?page=download&tid=348168 and rename it to test.torrent. How can I get the torrent file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use switch `--output-document=test.torrent` instead `-o`.

This should work.

```
$ wget "http://abc/?page=download&tid=348168" --output-document=test.torrent
```

---

For more information on `wget`, you can always,

```
$ man wget
```

or in app help,

```
$ wget --help | less
```